# Docker Compose PostgreSQL container fails to start due to missing directory

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm encountering an issue with my Docker Compose configuration where the PostgreSQL container fails to start due to a missing directory. Here are the details of my setup:

When I try to run `docker-compose up`, the PostgreSQL container fails to start, and I see the following error in the logs:

```
FATAL: could not create lock file "/postgres_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
```

I'm using Docker Compose to manage my application stack, which includes a PostgreSQL service.
I've mounted a custom PostgreSQL configuration file (`pg.conf`) into the container.
The error seems to be related to a missing directory `/postgres_socket`.

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
x-variables: &variables
  ENV_STAGE: local

services:
  profiles:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: compose/dev/web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./web/:/usr/src/web/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      <<: *variables
    env_file:
      - compose/dev/env/.env
      - compose/dev/env/.db.env
      - compose/dev/env/.data.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # - compose/dev/db/pg.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
      - ./compose/dev/db/pg.conf:/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=test
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    # command:
    #   - config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
    command: postgres -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf

    env_file:
      - compose/dev/env/.db.env

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

This is in my `pg.conf`:

```
listen_addresses = '0.0.0.0'
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /postgres_socket'
unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_permissions = 0777
max_connections = 100           # (change requires restart)
shared_buffers = 1GB            # min 128kB
work_mem = 256MB                # min 64kB
maintenance_work_mem = 2MB      # min 1MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix  # the default is the first option
effective_io_concurrency = 8        # 1-1000; 0 disables prefetching
max_worker_processes = 12       # (change requires restart)
wal_buffers = 16MB          # min 32kB, -1 sets based on shared_buffers
max_wal_size = 4GB
min_wal_size = 2GB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9  # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
random_page_cost = 1.0          # same scale as above
effective_cache_size = 512MB
default_statistics_target = 100 # range 1-10000
log_timezone = 'UTC+2'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'UTC'
lc_messages = 'en_US.utf8'          # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'en_US.utf8'          # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.utf8'           # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.utf8'              # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

What I've Tried:

I've checked my Docker Compose configuration and ensured that the necessary volumes are mounted.
I've created the missing directory `/postgres_socket` manually, but the issue persists.
I've verified the permissions of the directory and they seem to be correct.
Questions:

How can I resolve the issue of the missing directory `/postgres_socket`?
Are there any specific configurations or settings I need to adjust in my Docker Compose file or PostgreSQL configuration?
I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: That seems an odd location for the socket directory but maybe it is a docker thing. The directory will need to be writable by the "postgres" user inside the container. Is it?

Comment: Seems like the problem must be in './compose/dev/db/pg.conf'.  What is in it?  Where did it come from?

Comment: @jjanes, I added the `pg.conf` to the question. Please check it and let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: you probably dont need the unix socket connection in a docker container, if you leave that option empty, it should disable that and you should be fine

Comment: @MarianTheisen, Just to comment the whole line `unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /postgres_socket' in the `pg.conf` file?

Comment: It is very urgent task (to run the application), so I will appreciate any help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you need to take /postgres_socket out of the line:

```
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql, /postgres_socket'
```

But my question is, how did it get there? That is not the only setting that doesn't make much sense, so where did that file come from and why are you using it rather than the default one for the docker instance?

Comment: Actually, I just commented this line and now the database is running, but the application is not running. 

Can I share more details about it to help me?